# How can I relate to an object twice in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

I've got a Users model and a Tasks model.

A task has a creator, of type user, and an assignee of type user.

I've already done a migration of AddUserIdtoTasks to get the creator relation working, but now I need to do the same thing again to add the assignee, but I'm already using the keyword 'user'. How should I go about building a proper relation.

A task only has one assignee, always.

I'm using devise for the user model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
has_one :creator, :class_name => "User"
has_one :asignee, :class_name => "User"
```

Or `belongs_to`, depending on how your fields are set up. `has_one` and `belongs_to` both take an optional `:class_name` argument for cases just such as yours.

Comment: So would one be able to call creator_id or asignee_id ?

Answer (score 0):

Create the field `assignee_id` in your Task model and then use it for the relation as in

```
class Task < AR::Base
  belongs_to :assignee, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

On the other side of the relation

```
class User < AR::Base
  has_many: :assigned_tasks, :class_name => 'Task', :foreign_key => :assignee_id
end
```

Sorry, should be `:class_name`. Updated User class also with a `:foreign_key` parameter, without it `user.assigned_tasks` would have joined records using the `:user_id` parameter (the default value for has_many, i.e. "#{class_name}_id"`).

I invite you to read the link I've posted, it explains better than me all these things.

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to be picking up the class. Where did you get :assigned_tasks from - what's the logic behind that? FYI its a 1:1 relation.

Comment: I've updated my answer, it did contain a mistake. For the logic behind the name `:assigned_task` there is nothing. I picked up a name of my choice and then I've overridden AR conventions. You can change it as you wish.